# Trying to create a dynamic JavaScript mobile quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-mobile

I am Trying to create a dynamic java-script mobile quiz, where the user can dynamically add another (multiple) answers to a single question, like  "what is your favorite fruit(s)?"

I have seen examples here of the JavaScript: [Javascript Add Dynamic Input Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343991/javascript-add-dynamic-input-field)

But I haven't seen examples of anything that would erase the input field after the
user clicks the button "Submit and Add Another Fruit" so they can enter: (work on a mobile device)

- apples, click Submit and Add Another Fruit
- pears, click Submit and Add Another Fruit
- oranges, click Submit and Add Another Fruit
- kiwi, click Submit to next question

I was thinking the dynamically created input field name would
be question11.01, question11.02, question11.03, question11.04
or question/part: q001p1, q001p2, q001p3, q001p4

The solution also would need to work with a back submit button
in case the user realized he didn't want to add pears as the 2nd
fruit and changes that to banana

I hide the div after the user "Submit to next question"
and then make the next question div visible with javascript to give this that next page effect in a mobile device where the user feels like he is taking a dynamic quiz you would see at the DMV computer tests

```
<div class="questionquiz11" >



    <h2>Question 11</h2>
 <HR>

    <p>What is your favorite fruit(s)?   </p>

    <input type=text name="question11.01" >

 <BR> 

    <input type=submit id="backbutton"    value="Back">

    <input type=submit id="button"    value="Submit to next question">

    <input type=submit id="addfruit"  value="Submit and Add Another Fruit">



</div>



<div class="questionquiz12" style="display: none">



    <h2>Question 12</h2>
 <HR>

    <p>What is your favorite veggies(s)?   </p>

    <input type=text name="question12.01" >

 <BR> 

    <input type=submit id="backbutton"    value="Back">

    <input type=submit id="button"    value="Submit to next question">

    <input type=submit id="addveggies"  value="Submit and Add Another Veggie">



</div>
```

update: possible dynamic creating a div type sample code (doing some tests with it)

```
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery you should use `$("#..")` instead of `getElementById(...)` and other functions (i.e. `.html()` instead of innerHTML).

Comment: i'm trying to wrap my head around: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/

Comment: this seems more like the functionality I am look for:  http://www.fatihacet.com/lab/jQuiz/

Comment: A merge of those two examples I just posted in the comments above this comment, is what I am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a mix of both the ability to add input fields and navigate between questions, first recreate the example by mkyong inside a `<div>`. You can do this by using the jQuery [`.append(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function with another input box inside the append.

When the user navigates to the next question [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) the `<div>` of the question and [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) the `<div>` of the next question.