# Add Delete link / button to delete input field contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, wordpress

I am using an input form with multiple input fields.

These input fields can be pre-populated so I want to give the user an easy option of deleting then with a 'delete' link or button beside the field which deletes the full contents of that input field.

Pressing the delete button will also give them a text confirmation that it has been deleted.

I have attached a jpeg of what I am trying to do

[image]

I am using wordpress and gravity forms as my form builder. I am thinking maybe there is a jquery solution to do this but not sure how?

My code for one of my input fields is as follows, the inout fields on my form are all the same code but different id's of course so I did not want to paste everything here just 1 as an exmpale.

```
<li id="field_15_144" class="gfield">
  <label class="gfield_label" for="input_15_144">List</label>
    <div class="ginput_container">
    <input id="input_15_144" class="medium" type="text" tabindex="40" value="" name="input_144">
    </div>
  // this would be the link to delete the contents of input field "input_15_144
  <a href="" class="deleteURL">Delete</a>
</li>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: post your code what you have tried up to now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5344752/976777

Comment: @Dasun - yeah sorry I forgot to add it, done now...

Comment: @AravindVel thanks but that seems to talk about adding links / fields. I simply want to delete the contents of my field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="ginput_container">
    <input id="input_15_144" class="medium" type="text" tabindex="40" value="www.google.com" name="input_144">
    <a href="#" id="delete">delete</a>  <br/>      
        <span id="msg" style="color:green;"><span>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('a#delete').click(function(){
 $('input#input_15_144').val(''); 
 $('span#msg').html('deleted successfully');                            
});​
```

[***check the demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/RNYWt/)

You can do the styling as you want. I have created the simple eg which include the functionality you wanted. If you have any problems let me know.

Comment: Hi thank your for your answer. I have a bit of a problem when there are more than 1 field. They have unique id's but I can't get it to work. I modified your code here in the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RNYWt/1/ could you take another look?

Comment: I am really sorry to have to do this, but I just realised that my delete button is actually going to be in a separate li element underneath the field I want to delete..Really sorry I should of double checked from the beginning I just thought it would render this way and I can't change it as I am using gravity forms. I updated a JSfiddle here if you would be so kind to take another look http://jsfiddle.net/RNYWt/4/ thanks

Comment: if you want it that way you cannot generalize the coding like I wrote.  You will have to write a js code for separate event

Comment: thanks for the update but does not remove URL. If I was able to move the delete button inside the li element like this would it make it easier to do? http://jsfiddle.net/RNYWt/8/

Comment: Dasun just one final question, when I am implementing your solution into my code pressing the delete link just puts a # at the end of the Browser URL and shoots me up to the top of the page. I know it works fine in your fiddle, any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: cheers but same result. Don't worry I think your code is great it might be jquery not loading on my wordpress page or something silly like that..thanks

Comment: this might fix the problem(adding event to click handler). http://jsfiddle.net/RNYWt/11/. let me know whether that works for you

Comment: still the same thing. I don't think it is your code. As the input field does not get deleted on my site. I think someway the Javascript is not being inserted correctly by me or jquery is not loading correctly..thanks for all your help

Answer (score 2):

Here, I've added custom `ids` etc. for the fiddle. You can use it the way you like:

Older: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lewdh/) - [Lewdh](http://jsfiddle.net/Lewdh/)

## Edit

To meet newer requirements, some more edits were made.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lewdh/4/) - [Lewdh/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/Lewdh/4/)

## HTML Code

```
<li id="field_15_144" class="gfield">
  <label class="gfield_label" for="input_15_144">List</label>
    <div class="ginput_container" id="inpContain">
        <input id="input_15_144" class="medium" type="text" tabindex="40" value="http://jsfiddle.net/" name="input_144" />
        <button value="delete">Delete</button><br />
    </div>
</li>
<li id="field_15_145" class="gfield">
  <label class="gfield_label" for="input_15_145">List</label>
    <div class="ginput_container" id="inpContain">
        <input id="input_15_145" class="medium" type="text" tabindex="40" value="http://jsfiddle.net/" name="input_145" />
        <button value="delete">Delete</button><br />
    </div>
</li>
```

## jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li div button").on('click', function() {
        $(this).prev("input").val('');
        $(this).parent().append('<span style="color: green;">Success! Your link has been deleted.</span>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thats looks great. but how would this work on the same form with multiple inputs? I added another one to the JS fiddle but not sure how to add another ID in the JS? [link]http://jsfiddle.net/Lewdh/3/ - also what would be awesome is if that message did not appear everytime you press the button and duplicates.

Comment: @Redwall Still working on appending just once case, till then, check the edit. :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's val() does what you need. In the above example you could use a function like this.

```
$('#input_15_144').val('');
```

Comment: I'd wrap this into a function and just pass the element id to it via onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
 $(".ginput_container").append('<a href="#" onclick="return false;" id="delete_link">delete</a>'); // append a delete link

  $('#delete_link').click(function(){
      $('#input_15_144').val(''); // set the textfield empty
      $(".ginput_container").append('<br><span>Success - Your link has been deleted</span'); // put a success message
 });
});
```

You may apply css for the formatting

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i misunderstood your question but to reset input type text field, you only need to set its value to empty string:

```
$('#id').val('');
```