# How can I create columns in table dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a new column with the same of the old column when I click on the button.[desire output]

```js
$('#btnAddCol').click(function() {
  myform.find('tr').each(function() {
    var trow = $(this);
    if (trow.index() === 0) {
      trow.append('<td class="calculated-value">Chemical</td>');
    } else {
      trow.append('<td><input type="text" name="cb' + iter + '"/></td>');
    }
  });
  iter += 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btnAddCol" style="margin-left: 79%;">add column</button>
```

when I click on the add column button then new column create and contain column heading and input field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Add Dynamic Input Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343991/javascript-add-dynamic-input-field)

Comment: Where is the `table`?

Comment: You're [mcve] is broken. Just an fyi.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, if the table is blank from the beginning it will be able to run `each()` loop for `<tr>` because there is no one `<tr>`.

So, here I applied one heading in first row and a blank textbox in second row, it means each() loop will be play for two times for each `<tr>`.

Check below code :

```js
var iter = 0;
$('#btnAddCol').click(function () {
    $('#myTable tr').each(function (e) {
        var trow = $(this);
        if (trow.index() === 0) {
            trow.append('<td class="calculated-value">Chemical</td>');
        } else {
            trow.append('<td><input type="text" name="cb' + iter + '" /></td>');
        }
    });
    iter++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
    <tr><td>Heading</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="cb'+iter+'" /></td></tr>
</table>


<button type="button" id="btnAddCol" style="margin-left: 79%;">add column</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addColumn(){

if($(".td_class").length>0){
$("#tr1").append('<td class="td_class"><input type="text"></td>');
}else{
$("#tr1").append('<td class="td_class">Chemical</td>');
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr id="tr1"></tr>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="addColumn()">Add Column</button>
```

Is this the answer you want?

Comment: i want to append column wise not row

Comment: Whilst this is a simple question and answer, it's usually worth explaining your answer, breaking it apart.